# Plotting multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

l have four variables y1,y2,y3,y4. I want to make a plot that will show how y2,y3 and y4 behave in relation to y1. I have tried using scatterplot but l do not get much information from that.

Comment: Some data and a paste of what you've tried would help folks know where to go answer-wise.

Comment: separate plot for each variable? plot separate lines all on the same plot? what form does your data take?

Answer (score 1):

`matplot` might be useful here as well:

```
dat <- data.frame(y1=1:3,y2=1:3,y3=2:4,y4=3:5)
matplot(dat[1],dat[-1],type="l",lty=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))  #make a plot area with space for three plots
y1=rnorm(100)
y2=rnorm(100)
y3=rnorm(100)
y4=rnorm(100)


plot(y1,y2)
plot(y1,y3)
plot(y1,y3)
```